# Can grease pencil be set to occlude freestyle lines?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil, freestyle

I'm trying to do a scene that mixes 2D and 3D together and uses Freestyle to give the 3D elements a little bit of line work. The problem I have is that the lines are showing through my grease pencil layers, including solid fills. Is there a way to get EEVEE and freestyle to respect GP as a solid object that would block freestyle lines? (I prefer to avoid rendering multiple passes and compositing together afterward.)